# use sed to replace a range of hex values

Tags: sed, hex

I want to replace the series of hex characters from x'00 to x'40' to spaces in my file. 
I would not want to write a sed -e 's/\x00//g' for each one of them.. is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 4):

This may do it for you, depending on your environment and version of sed. (It avoids messing with tab, but there's no reason to avoid space since you're just replacing it with another space.)

```
LANG='' sed 's/[\x00-\x08\x0A-\x40]/ /g'
```

This clears LANG for the duration of the sed command. That can solve some problems if you're environment is UTF8, for example.

Comment: Correct. Otherwise this will result in the well-known error of `sed: -e expression #1, char XX: Invalid collation character`. However, I've never understood _why_ this happens in an UTF-8 environment. And using one more byte, i. e. using `\x0008` instead of `\x08` didn't do the trick, either.

Comment: @syntaxerror check out https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Locale-Considerations.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `tr` instead of `sed`.  First you must convert your character codes from hex to octal.  Let's say you want 0 to 77 octal.  Here that is:

```
tr '\0-\77' ' ' < your-input-file
```

Comment: what does your command really do.. change anything with octal values starting with 0 replaced with octal value of 77..

Comment: I tried the translate and it works .. the only thing is I discovered I have to eliminate the octal value of TAB and SPACE in the list.. did the command in three lines: 
cat my-input-file |tr '\000-\010' ' '|tr '\012-\037' ' ' > my-input-file1
Is there a way to combine the tr combine into one ...

Comment: If what you really want is to convert "special" characters to spaces,  you could try `tr [:special:] ' '` - the [:special:] character class might better mirror your actual requirements.

Answer (score 0):

this:

```
LC_ALL=C sed 's/[\x00-\x40]/ /g'
```

or rough:

```
(LC_ALL=C; sed 's/[\x00-\x40]/ /g')
```

Test:

```
alias hxr="perl -ne'for(split){print chr hex}'"

printf '%02X ' `seq 65` | hxr | hd

printf '%02X ' `seq 65` | hxr | LC_ALL=C sed 's/[\x00-\x40]/ /g'; echo
```